# Comparing null values in Caché

Tags: sql, null, intersystems-cache

I have this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Ens.MessageHeader head ,EnsLib_HL7.Message as body
WHERE   head.MessageBodyId = body.ID
AND     body.Name IN ('ADT^A34','ADT^A40')
AND     MessageBodyClassName = 'EnsLib.HL7.Message'
```

Which gives results like this:

[image]

I want to only get the records where BusinessProcessId is null so I add this line:

```
AND     BusinessProcessId IS NULL
```

But now I get no results.

[image]

I've tried a few variants but nothing seems to do what I expect.   What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may simply not have enough matches on your inner join, it's hard to tell since I don't have access to your data. Try commenting out the last line and if you don't get any results comment out the last 2 lines of your query. If you do get results it means that one of these 2 lines filters out all the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Ens.MessageHeader head, EnsLib_HL7.Message as body
WHERE  BusinessProcessId IS NULL
```

if it yields any results, then recheck other query conditions.

Comment: I see what I did and it was really dumb... I was initially using `$PIECE(rawcontent,"|",9)` to compare the message type (ADT^A34) but I decided it would be cleaner to use `body.name` well when I switched the field I didn't switch the data format, which is now "ADT_A34".  /facepalm